# Adobe Reader XI doesn't allow the editing of fields in a document after it's been edited?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

One of the users at our company has a `*.pdf` file she received from the state of Pennsylvania.

The version of Adobe Reader she is using is `Adobe Reader XI 11.0.3`.

She uses this `pdf` file to send in a report.

Her workflow goes like this:

1. She makes a copy of the file.
2. She opens the file and the file displays in purple at the top:

   - `Please fill out the following form.  You can save data typed into this form`.
   - `Highlight Existing Fields`
3. She fills in the specifics by entering values into the form fields.
4. A few weeks later she returns to the same `pdf` document and can no longer edit the fields, instead she gets the following message:

> "This document enabled extended features in Adobe Reader.  The document
>   has been changed since it was created and use of extended features is
>   no longer available.  Please contact the author for the original
>   version of this document."

She's also running Windows 7 and I've been told that the issue was once fixed by setting compatibility mode on Adobe Reader XI to Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Could it be a user profile issue???

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I tried changing the compatibility mode (among other things) and that didn't solve anything. It seems that once a document starts showing that message, it can no longer be filled in by Adobe Reader.

The solutions seem to be to either use:

- [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat.html) or
- [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/)

I opted for Foxit Reader since it's free. It seems to continue to allow filling in documents that Adobe Reader won't.

Comment: Yes, I can edit the fields using Foxit Reader and the edits are saved in the PDF file. Then I can view the saved edits etc. in Adobe Reader but will not be able to edit the fields in Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was forced to purchase Adobe Acrobat Pro and re-save the file to get this to work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @m4573r lleand00 *is* the original question author

Comment: @DavidPostill Well, it still isn't really an answer. If I have the same problem, should I rely on a "I believe [...]" answer, and purchase the software again? It seemed more like a comment to the original question (although I agree that the phrasing of the default comment message when I voted to close is unfortunate)

Comment: @m4573r let's see if he updates his "answer"